Way to autoplay the video without muted
<div class="tab-img">
            <video id="autplay-video" width="320" height="240" controls autoplay
                poster="https://solax-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/Thumbnail+English-SOLAx+Video.jpg">
                <!-- <source src="https://solax-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/English+Demo+(Final).mp4" type="video/mp4" /> -->
                <source src="https://solax-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/English+Demo+(Final).mp4" type="video/ogg" />
            </video>
            <button id="playButton" onclick="playonclick()" style="display: none;">Play Video</button>
        </div>

I tried the js and jQuery for unmuting the video , and also tryed the different event for that.

The video itself is not muted, so is it being muted on your side or ?

There is no way to do autoplay of unmuted video

Your question is not clear. I had tried your code and it should autoplay the video as unmuted. Would you like to make it muted or anything else?

There are restrictions to what the browser will do in the case of autoplaying video/audio:

As a general rule, you can assume that media will be allowed to autoplay only if at least one of the following is true:

The audio is muted or its volume is set to 0
The user has interacted with the site (by clicking, tapping, pressing keys, etc.)
If the site has been allowlisted; this may happen either automatically if the browser determines that the user engages with media frequently, or manually through preferences or other user interface features
If the autoplay Permissions Policy is used to grant autoplay support to an <iframe> and its document.


Autoplay availability
Often you just need the user to interact with the page before you can turn on the audio.
